# Return a promise from a custom function

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, promise, bluebird

<sup>*Originally asked on [GitHub](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/510)*</sup>

---

Hi,

Can you please show me how to return a promise from a custom function using bluebird? Here's what I'm working with:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var P = require('bluebird');

var redisSessionStore = new RedisStore({client: redisClient});
P.promisifyAll(redisSessionStore);

redisSessionStore.getAsync('active_session').then(function(data) {  
    if(!data || (data.timestamp < Data.now())) {
        return sulogin(params);
    }
}).then(function(values) { // expecting sulogin to return a promise
  // do another async call
});

function sulogin(params){

}
```

How can I make sulogin return a promise?

Comment: You wrote this lib, right?

Comment: Yes, but I am just redirecting this from github

Comment: @georg He posted this on my behalf as I originally posted this to https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/510

Comment: Ah, ok, that just got confusing.

Comment: @drecute what does `sulogin` look like? It's just empty here...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum As at writing I didn't know what to do. But thanks to https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/196

Comment: Was your sulogin an async function or not?

Answer (score -1):

I modified sulogin to look like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function sulogin(arg, fn) {
    Promise.props({
        host:"localhost",
        port: 8080,
        path: '/uaa/login.do',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function(result) {
        return http.requestAsync(result);
    });
}
```

Thanks to https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/196

Comment: That props call is pointless - you can just `requestAsync` on the literal. Also don't forget to `return` the promise